# React native fetch api get son data

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native, fetch-api

How do I print the data on my screen?

https://snack.expo.io/@enverkoseler/denemedata

```html
<div data-snack-id="@enverkoseler/denemedata" data-snack-platform="ios" data-snack-preview="true" data-snack-theme="light" style="overflow:hidden;background:#fafafa;border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.08);border-radius:4px;height:505px;width:100%"></div>
<script async src="https://snack.expo.io/embed.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You fetch an object, not an array. So `dataSource: responseJson[0]` does not make sense. Since your FlatList component requires an array, change `dataSource: responseJson[0]` by `[responseJson]`.

Comment: thankss.!!! It's working. I'm really grateful for your help. be there :)